# Ado.net iterating through each column in row of SqlDataReader

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ado.net

I am writing a simple XML web service and want to return raw XML. I am doing this by creating a string literal that represents the XML. My data source is a SqlDataReader object that contains the results of a stored proc call. The way I am doing it right now is by using a while loop and reading values from the item property like so :

```
'string builder to create the literal
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
sb.Append("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>")
sb.Append("<members>")

'dr is an instance of SqlDataReader
While (dr.Read())
    sb.Append("<member>")
    sb.Append(String.Concat("<PersonnelID>", dr.Item("PersonnelID"), "</PersonnelID>"))
    sb.Append(String.Concat("<FirstName>", dr.Item("FirstName"), "</FirstName>"))
    sb.Append("</member>")
End While
sb.Append("</members>")
```

The issue is there are over a dozen fields that are returned from the stored proc and writing each of them out like that seems inefficient. Is there a way to iterate through each row getting the column name and the value, so I could do something like this:

```
sb.Append(String.Concat("<",ColName,">", dr.Item(ColName), "</",ColName,">"))
```

Could anyone suggest how I could do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work (added the using-statement just  for the sake of completeness):

```
Using dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    sb.Append("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>")
    sb.Append("<members>")
    While (dr.Read())
        sb.Append("<member>")
        For i = 0 To dr.FieldCount - 1
            sb.Append(String.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>", dr.GetName(i), dr(i)))
        Next
        sb.Append("</member>")
    End While
    sb.Append("</members>")
End Using
```

- [`SqlDataReader.GetName` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getname%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [`String.Format` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)
- [`SqlDataReader.FieldCount` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.fieldcount.aspx)